# insert json to another json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two json

```
var json1={
  key1: 'val1',
  key2: 'val2'
}
var json2={
  key3: 'val3',
  key4: 'val4'
}
```

I want a thrird json with the values from json1 and json2, like this:

```
json3 = {
  key1: 'val1',
  key2: 'val2',
  key3: 'val3',
  key4: 'val4'
}
```

how can make it posible?, thanks ;)

Comment: Please read this: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a spread of es6

```
var json1={
 key1: 'val1',
 key2: 'val2'
}
var json2={
 key3: 'val3',
 key4: 'val4'
}
var json3 = {...json1,...json2}

 // json3 echo json3 = { key1: 'val1',key2: 'val2',key3: 'val3',key4: 'val4'}
```

Comment: thanks!!! it is!!!

Comment: Yes, See  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: I accepted your answer because reading more, it is the most recent way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign` like the following:

```
Object.assign({}, json1, json2);
```

```js
var json1={
  key1: 'val1',
  key2: 'val2'
}
var json2={
  key3: 'val3',
  key4: 'val4'
}

console.log(Object.assign({}, json1, json2))
```

Comment: thanks man, i was lost 2 hours lookin for that !!! in that case, it could be:
    json3 = Object.assign(json1, json2);
thanks a lot...